# React Syntax error on adding a second class on Toggle

Tags: html, css, class, reactjs, sass

How can i add second class to my `<div>` "button" if i append 'toggle-button' the class doesn't work.

```
<CSSTransitionGroup
    transitionName="buttonAninmated"
    transitionEnterTimeout={300}
    transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
>
    <div className={['toggle-button', this.state.active ? 'active-button': null]} onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</CSSTransitionGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it by using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
className = {`toggle-button ${this.state.active ? `active-button` : ``}`}
```

Or write it by using `+`:

```
className = {"toggle-button " + this.state.active ? "active-button" : ""}
```

To apply multiple classes, write all the class names **space separated**.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div className={"toggle-button " + (this.state.active ? 'active-button' : '')}>
```

note the space after toggle-button